# grunt-depend-concat is not replace @depend tags with file contents

Tags: gruntjs, concatenation

I'm trying to use [grunt-depend-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-depend-concat) to create a site.uncompressed.js file with the contents of all the dependencies using @depend tags in my site.js file. The destination file is being created, but the @depend comments are still at the top of the file. Am I using this grunt package correctly? Is there a problem with my code? I'm open to alternative Grunt packages if I can still use @depend tags, but the grunt package documentation is rather sparse and I can figure out how else it might be possible to do this.

site.js (partial):

```
/**
 * @depend vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
 * @depend vendor/jquery.smooth-scroll-1.4.13.min.js
 […]
 */

[…]
```

Gruntfile.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
}());

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        filepaths: {
            assetDir: 'httpdocs/files/assets/',
            jsDir: '<%= filepaths.assetDir %>' + 'js/',
            jsSrc: '<%= filepaths.jsDir %>' + 'site.js',
            jsComb: '<%= filepaths.jsDir %>' + 'site.uncompressed.js',
            jsMin: '<%= filepaths.jsDir %>' + 'site.min.js';
        },

    'depend-concat': {
        depend_doctag: {
            options: {
                method: {
                    type: 'doctag',
                    tag: 'depend'
                }
            },
            src: ['<%= filepaths.jsSrc %>'],
            dest: '<%= filepaths.jsComb %>'
        },
    },
    uglify: {
        options: {
            preserveComments: false,
            banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */',
            sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                '<%= filepaths.jsMin %>': ['<%= filepaths.jsComb %>']
            }
        }
    }
});

require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'depend-concat', 'uglify']);
};
```

Grunt Output:

> Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
>
> >> 2 files lint free.
>
> Running "depend-concat:depend_doctag" (depend-concat) task File
>   "httpdocs/files/assets/js/site.uncompressed.js"
>   created.
>
> Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
>
> >> 1 sourcemap created.
>
> >> 1 file created.
>
> Done, without errors.

site.uncompressed.js (partial):

```
/**
 * @depend vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
 * @depend vendor/jquery.smooth-scroll-1.4.13.min.js
 […]
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have not been able to get this Grunt plugin to work properly, so I have given up on using grunt-depend-concat with @depend rules in the site.js file.

I added a section to filepaths in the Gruntfile, then used the [grunt-contrib-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-concat) plugin instead.